# Duplicated a JavaScript onclick function, only the original works?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm very new to all this and am trying to duplicate an image with a JavaScript `onclick` function attached to it. I've duplicated the image and the coding and have placed it onto a new page, but the `onclick` function does not seem to work. However the original works just fine. The original `onclick` opens up a modal window, but the duplicated one does nothing.

What am I missing?

Here is the image with the `onclick` function:

```
<img id="product-bump-<?php echo $product->ID; ?>" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets_consumer/assets/img/bump-icon_.png" width="20"   class="product-arrow" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Bump" onclick="javascript:bump_hype_product(<?php echo $product->ID; ?>, 'B')" />
```

Here is the function located in my `consumer-global.js` file:

```
function bump_hype_product(post_id, type_text){
jQuery('#product-message-confirmation-wrap').hide();
jQuery('.popup-waiting-wrap').show();
jQuery('#modal_product_message_confirmation h4.modal-title').html('');

jQuery.ajax({
    url : the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        action : 'bump_hype_product',
        type : type_text,
        post_id : post_id
    },
    success : function( response ) {

        jQuery('.popup-waiting-wrap').hide();
        jQuery('#product-message-confirmation-wrap').show();
        jQuery('#product-message-confirmation-wrap').html(response);

        jQuery('#modal_product_message_confirmation').modal('show');
    }
});
```

The script file is listed in the header of all my pages.

Comment: your onclick listener doesn't apply to your newly created image. You have to make a listener on a parent element and if the target element of the click is an image then duplicate it

Comment: Open the Console of your browser's developer tools. Click on the image. Look at what the error messages say.

Answer (score 0):

As you duplicating image with javascript function,
that dynamically generated image will not bind up with HTML Dom so you facing this issue.
Search for Delegate event of Jquery and restructure your code with delegate event.
it will work !!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('staticElement').on('click','#dynamicallyAddedElament',handlerFunctio);
```

this will add event listener to your static element so that dynamically elements added inside that static div can be binded.

Comment: So where do i put this code? sorry im new to this and am practically editing existing code

Comment: you can put it inside script tag of your page or you can write a separate .js file and include it on your page

Comment: can i use php inside the script to call the element ID?

Comment: no, PHP is a back end language browser only understands HTML, javascript and other front end languages.

Comment: im sure this is actually so simple, but i still cannot achieve it. i need clarification on what a static element actually is? and the handlerFunction?